# tensoring with flat module factors the kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, flatness

I want to show that if $F$ is a flat $R$-module, then for any $R$-homomorphism $\varphi: M \rightarrow N$, we have 
$$\ker (1_F \otimes \varphi) \cong F \otimes \ker \varphi $$

The $\supset$ direction is trivial. For the $\subset$ direction, I use the fact that $F\otimes(-)$ preserves the injectivity of the map 
$$ M /\ker \varphi \overset{\tilde{\varphi}}{\rightarrow} N $$ 
Thus if $f\otimes m \in \ker (1_F \otimes \varphi)$, i.e. $f\otimes [m]$ mapped to $0$ under $1_F \otimes \tilde{\varphi}$, we have $f\otimes [m] =0$. This suggests me to complete the proof by showing
$$ F\otimes \frac{M}{\ker\varphi} \cong \frac{F\otimes M}{F\otimes \ker\varphi} $$
Is this relation true? It seems very plausible for me that $f\otimes[m] \mapsto [f\otimes m]$ gives the isomorphism. But I struggle at the injectivity part of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F$ is flat, tensoring with it preserves exactness of *all* exact sequences; from
$$
0\to\ker f\to M\xrightarrow{f} N \to \operatorname{coker}f\to 0
$$
you get the exact sequence
$$
0\to F\otimes\ker f\to  F\otimes M\xrightarrow{1_F\otimes f}  F\otimes N \to  F\otimes\operatorname{coker}f\to 0
$$
which is (isomorphic to) the standard kernel-cokernel sequence for $1_F\otimes f$. Hence
$$
\ker(1_F\otimes f)\cong F\otimes\ker f
$$

Comment: very neat! thanks! what about the isomorphism of tensor products I tried to prove? Is it true?

Comment: @zudumazics You're basically trying to prove it in the same fashion, considering instead the two exact sequences $0\to\ker f\to M\to M/\ker f\to 0$ and $0\to M/\ker f\to N\to\operatorname{coker}f\to0$ (where $\operatorname{coker}f=N/\operatorname{im}f$).